# How do I avoid exceeding the 5 topic limit when sending FCM notifications to certain topics while using boolean operations?

Tags: laravel, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are developing an application, the app itself is made in Ionic (Angular) and the server is running in Laravel (PHP) on an Amazon EC2 instance. The app uses the [Capacitor FCM plugin](https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm) to receive notifications from FCM, and the server uses [Laravel FCM plugin](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM) to send notifications.

In the app, a registered user chooses several options, such as age range, address (region), gender, among other things. Let's assume we have the ages

- 10's~20's = *age-1*
- 30's = *age-2*
- 40's = *age-3*
- 50's = *age-4*

and address regions

- Asia = *area-1*
- Europe = *area-2*
- America = *area-3*
- Australia = *area-4*

and gender

- Female = *gender-1*
- Male = *gender-2*

The app subscribes to the topics that are based on what options the user chooses, for example, if he chooses 30's, America, and Male, then he will be subscribed to the topics *age-2*, *area-3*, and *gender-2*.

Here is where the problem arises.

From the server, we will need to send notifications to users that are subscribed to specific topics.

At first, we tried using boolean operations, so that when we can send notifications to people that are subscribed to the topics (*age-2* or *age-3*) and (*area-1* or *area-2* or *area-4*) and (*gender-1*). The problem is, FCM does not allow more than 5 topics to be specified in the condition, in this case, 6 is being specified. (In reality, we can reach up to 17 topics in one sending)

Since that failed, we tried sending in batches, such that (*age-2* or *age-3*) and (*area-1* or *area-3*) will be sent in batches of

- (*age-2*) and (*area-1*)
- (*age-2*) and (*area-3*)
- (*age-3*) and (*area-1*)
- (*age-3*) and (*area-3*)

but we quickly realized that that means some people will get the notification more than once (since some fields are multiple selection, for example, a user might choose both Asia and America), and that is of course, undesirable.

We are running out of options besides using device tokens to send notifications to people individually, but we can have up to as many as 50,000 users. We are afraid that sending notifications to people individually might take some time. We are using [Laravel Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues) to process the sending of notifications in the background, but we are still kind of afraid of what might happen if we send notifications individually. Besides, that implementation sounds so dirty and far from optimal, which makes me think there should be better ways.

I would like to kindly ask if anyone knows of a way to solve this situation. We did consider using Amazon SNS, but it seems that SNS is lacking topic boolean conditions and it's quite difficult to implement on both app and server.

I would really, really appreciate any ideas, opinions, any guidance. I tried my best, but couldn't think of a better solution.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I was facing the exact same situation for an Ionic app as well. The FCM 5 topics limit and multiple topic selection in the app ended in some users receiving the same notification multiple times, as you mentioned. On the other hand, for example, it's not possible to send a single notification to multiple iOS device tokens using the Apple Push Notification service. It seems that companies that does not use FCM must have a robust infrastructure to store device tokens and associated topics, and send notifications accordingly. Unfortunately, I haven't found any guide to implement sush system yet.

Comment: "We are running out of options besides using device tokens to send notifications to people individually, but we can have up to as many as 50,000 users. We are afraid that sending notifications to people individually might take some time." Behind the scenes Firebase's topics simply fan out to calls to send to the individual tokens too. FCM's infrastructure is used by millions of apps to send many billions of messages a day, so it can handle scale quite well.

Comment: @Reqven I see. Thank you very much for your response! On the server side, we know what each user has selected, so we can get a list of users that should receive a certain notification and send a notification to those user's device tokens, but I was worrying that that is not the optimal solution, so I was thinking (or asking) or alternatives. Maybe that's the only way to go.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen We aren't that concerned about notifications arriving to users late, but more about whether problems will arise if we just send a notification to a bunch of device tokens that may reach up to 10,000~50,000. Like, would the FCM API send a "too many request" error after a certain number of calls, or maybe some other problems... This is really hard, sorry.

Comment: As said: FCM's infrastructure is used by millions of apps to send many billions of messages a day, so it can handle scale quite well. 10K-50K may be a lot for your app, but it's not for FCM. Just try to minimize the number of API calls you do (for example by using batch sends where possible), and you should be fine.

Comment: Ah, so we can batch API calls to send notifications to multiple device tokens in one call, I see! I guess I missed that from the Firebase notification. I did check Laravel FCM's documentation, and I did see that one can send a notification to multiple device tokens. However, I thought that if there are 1,000 device tokens, it will internally send 1,000 different API requests, but checking Laravel FCM's plugin code, it actually groups 1,000 tokens into one request. I guess that's something we can handle. Thank you very much for your guidance--I honestly do appreciate it!

Comment: @Kyle Alexander Buan
I am facing exactly the same issue, did you find any workaround ?